# Increasing memory usage while scrolling on listview items in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, idisposable

In a WinForm i have two listview(lvwTemplateCategory) one is listing folders at given directory and if you select folder, other listview(lvwTemplates) shows the files under this directory. I have also one picturebox(picTemplateImage) to show preview screenshot of that file.

While i'm scrolling on that form for 2-3 folders and 9-10 files it's memory usage goes from 62 MB to 120 MB.

I don't know how to manage the memory source also i tried to implement IDisposable but not know where to implement.

P.S. I'm using VS 2017 and calling that WinForm with .Show() method.

Also if you see non-logic codes please let me know.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmCreateNewModel
    Implements IDisposable

    Private Sub LoadForm(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call AddRootDatabase()
        splCreateNewModel.Panel2Collapsed = True
        Size = New Size(946, 800)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ViewLargeIcons(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdViewLargeIcons.Click
        lvwTemplateCategory.View = View.LargeIcon
    End Sub

    Private Sub ViewListIcons(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdViewList.Click
        lvwTemplateCategory.View = View.List
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddRootDatabase()
        Try
            Dim DirDB As String = My.Settings.str_db__path_tpl

            Dim DirInfoDB As New DirectoryInfo(DirDB)
            For Each TplDirDB As DirectoryInfo In DirInfoDB.GetDirectories
                If Not (TplDirDB.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = FileAttributes.Hidden Then
                    cboTemplateDatabase.Items.Add(TplDirDB.Name)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub SelectRootDatabase(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboTemplateDatabase.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            lvwTemplateCategory.Items.Clear()
            lvwTemplates.Items.Clear()
            Dim DirTempRootDir As String = My.Settings.str_db__path_tpl & "\" & cboTemplateDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString
            Dim DirTempDbInfo As New DirectoryInfo(DirTempRootDir)
            Dim lstIcon As Integer
            For Each TplCatDir As DirectoryInfo In DirTempDbInfo.GetDirectories
                If Not (TplCatDir.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = FileAttributes.Hidden Then
                    If imgIcons.Images.ContainsKey(TplCatDir.Name) = True Then
                        lstIcon = imgIcons.Images.IndexOfKey(TplCatDir.Name)
                    Else
                        lstIcon = imgIcons.Images.IndexOfKey("default")
                    End If
                    lvwTemplateCategory.Items.Add(TplCatDir.Name, lstIcon)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub SelectTemplateCategory(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvwTemplateCategory.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (CInt(lvwTemplateCategory.SelectedItems.Count.ToString) = 0) Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim DirTempCatDir As String = My.Settings.str_db__path_tpl & "\" & cboTemplateDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString & "\" & lvwTemplateCategory.SelectedItems(0).Text.ToString
        Dim DirTempInfo As New DirectoryInfo(DirTempCatDir)
        lvwTemplates.Items.Clear()
        Try
            For Each TplFile As FileInfo In DirTempInfo.GetFiles
                If Not (TplFile.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = FileAttributes.Hidden Then
                    If Path.GetExtension(TplFile.Name) = ".spck" Or Path.GetExtension(TplFile.Name) = ".buspck" Then
                        lvwTemplates.Items.Add(TplFile.Name)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub SelectTemplate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvwTemplates.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (CInt(lvwTemplates.SelectedItems.Count.ToString) = 0) Then
            cmdQuickConfigure.Enabled = False
            Return
        End If
        cmdQuickConfigure.Enabled = True

        Dim TemplFileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lvwTemplates.SelectedItems(0).Text.ToString)
        Dim DirTempDir As String = My.Settings.str_db__path_tpl & "\" & cboTemplateDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString & "\" & lvwTemplateCategory.SelectedItems(0).Text.ToString & "\" & TemplFileName
        Dim imagePath As String = DirTempDir & ".png"
        If File.Exists(imagePath) Then
            picTemplateImage.ImageLocation = (imagePath)
            picTemplateImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            picTemplateImage.Load()
        Else
            picTemplateImage.Image = picTemplateImage.ErrorImage
        End If
        txtModelName.Text = lvwTemplates.SelectedItems(0).Text.ToString
    End Sub
    Private Sub VisualViewControl(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdVisualControl.Click
        If splCreateNewModel.Panel2Collapsed = False Then
            splCreateNewModel.Panel2Collapsed = True
            Size = New Size(946, 800)
            cmdVisualControl.Text = ">>"
        Else
            cmdVisualControl.Text = "<<"
            splCreateNewModel.Panel2Collapsed = False
            Size = New Size(1300, 800)

        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub BrowseDirectory(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdBrowseDirectory.Click
        Try
            Dim sfd As New SelectFolderDialog With {
                .Title = "Select a folder"
            }
            If sfd.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
                txtModelDirectory.Text = sfd.FolderName
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
        Private Sub DialogOK(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdOk.Click
        CreateModel()
        Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DialogCancel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: .NET applications will increase their memory usage as they create new objects. The memory usage won't go down as old objects are discarded because it's quicker to just keep allocating new memory. From time to time, the garbage collector will clean up and reclaim that memory. Try minimising your form and see if the memory usage goes down. That will often happen as the GC will kick in then. Generally speaking, there's no need for you to worry about resource management other than to ensure that you dispose objects that support it when you're done with them.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your explanaition. Yes i monitorizing GC clean up a bit memory but i thought i was making something wrong but you're saying no problem. Thanks.